# \vfill in tcolorbox with sidebyside

Tags: tcolorbox, vertical-spacing

I have some unbreakable variable height sidebyside tcolorboxes.

At the bottom of those boxes I want to have on the left side a line, and on the right side a "please seperate here" text on the same level as the line.

I have no fixed height, so I cannot set this attribute (?).

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top]
on left: \lipsum[1]
\vfill
\mbox{}{ \hrule}
\tcblower
text
\vfill
please separate here
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,sidebyside align=top]
text
\vfill
\mbox{}{ \hrule}
\tcblower
on right:\lipsum[2]
\vfill
please separate here
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper and lower contents of a side-by-side `tcolorbox` is put in `minipage` environments respectively. Until the height of `minipage` is specified, a `\vfill` used in it will have no effect.

In the following example, the desired effect is emulated by `overlay` option. Some internal dimensions of `tcolorbox` and two (avoidable) magic numbers (10pt, 12pt) are used.

```tex
\documentclass[notitlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  my sidebyside/.style={
    sidebyside, sidebyside align=top,
    enhanced, geometry nodes,
    bottom=2mm+14.4pt,
    overlay={
      \draw ([shift={(\kvtcb@leftupper+\kvtcb@boxsep, 10pt)}]frame.south west) 
         -- ([shift={(-.5*\kvtcb@sbs@gap, 10pt)}]frame.south);
      \node[shift={(.5*\kvtcb@sbs@gap, 10pt)}, inner sep=0pt, anchor=base west] at (frame.south) {please separate here};
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[my sidebyside]
  \lipsum[2]
  \tcblower
  right-side is shorter
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[my sidebyside]
  left-side is shorter
  \tcblower
  \lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]